# JavaScript filter should return arrays if the id match

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have  books data. I'd like to return the books if they match the author's id. When I try to filter out data that does not match my 'author's' id. However, it always returns all book data.

```js
const author = "AUTHOR#e9bb9d29-7f20-4fce-892c-6a155dbee42c";

const Book = [
  {
    publishingYear: "2020",
    rating: 5.2,
    GSI1SK: "AUTHOR#a731ea70-f3f3-4811-9734-f22c0856385d",
    genre: ["adventure", "drama", "scifi"],
    GSI1PK: "AUTHOR",
    page: 100,
    publisher: "Afternoon pub",
    SK: "BOOK#c4a58f20-4977-4db8-9723-0185f68cdf01",
    price: "3.50",
    PK: "BOOKS",
    author: "Krishna",
    title: "Me and mySelf"
  },
  {
    publishingYear: "2020",
    rating: 5.2,
    GSI1SK: "AUTHOR#6b7c10ff-0e2c-46bd-9697-3b51730d8b29",
    genre: ["adventure", "drama", "scifi"],
    GSI1PK: "AUTHOR",
    page: 100,
    publisher: "Day pub",
    SK: "BOOK#e4773a32-5451-42c6-a3f1-a6aa45176256",
    price: "3.50",
    PK: "BOOKS",
    author: "John doe",
    title: "Hello world"
  },
  {
    publishingYear: "2020",
    rating: 5.2,
    GSI1SK: "AUTHOR#a731ea70-f3f3-4811-9734-f22c0856385d",
    genre: ["adventure", "drama", "scifi"],
    GSI1PK: "AUTHOR",
    page: 100,
    publisher: "Night Pub",
    SK: "BOOK#fb56a876-41bc-49f9-9762-c48e90af3117",
    price: "3.50",
    PK: "BOOKS",
    author: "Krishna",
    title: "Amazing Race"
  }
];

const Books = Book.filter((i) => {
  console.log(i.GSI1SK);
  i.GSI1SK === author;
  return i;
});

console.log(Books);
```

Comment: `return i.GSI1SK === author;` not `i`. Every object `i` is truthy. As an aside, I wouldn't use `i` for anything but an index. Prefer `e` for element or `o` for object.

Answer (score 2):

You are using filter the wrong way, you should return true or false based on the condition you're matching,

```
const Books = Book.filter((i) => {
  console.log(i.GSI1SK);
  return i.GSI1SK === author;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

And you can omit unnecessary lines. Try this.

```
const Books = Book.filter(i => i.GSI1SK === author)
```